# Find sub folder in a file path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Sorry I have searched and googled but I can't seem to find what I'm after;

I have a list of filepaths like below:

```
/ReportingFolder/SubjectFolder/ReportName
```

I need to get the SubjectFolder, what is the simplest way?

I have tried the below but that gives me the ReportingFolder:

```
LEFT((substring(Path, 2, (LEN(Path) - 1))), CHARINDEX('/', (substring(Path, 2,(LEN(Path) - 1)))) - 1) AS Folder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SUBSTRING (
    path,
    CHARINDEX('/',path,2)+1,
    CHARINDEX('/',path,CHARINDEX('/',path,2)+2)-CHARINDEX('/',path,2)-1
    )
```